# Where is the Spring 17 "Approval Requests" tab?

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, bug, spring17

I am trying to see the "Approval Requests" tab and list that is supposed to come in the Spring 17 release, but I cannot find it to add it to my app.

On my custom app - I am searching for the "Approval Requests" tab and cannot find it in the available tab list:

[image]

Does anyone know how can I add it to my app?

**UPDATE**

I can go to this tab in 2 ways:

1. From the homepage "Items To Approve" component by clicking the "view all" link:

[image]

2. By opening the AppLauncher and finding the tab "Approval Requests:

[image]

BUT, I cannot add this tab to by on my top navigation bar - this is my problem

Comment: Does your profile have the permission for it?

Comment: I cannot find any permission for the approval object or tab, what permission am I looking for? I am a sys admin of the org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it!!!

So - if your custom app is old (created with classic Salesforce), if you edit it you get the old application editor (like you see in my question), and there you don't have the Approval Requests tab. You also don't have the Calendar and Task tab (I was looking for them and this is how I found the solution).

But if you create a new custom app from within lightning - you get the new application editor, and over there you can see and select the Approval Requests tab and also the Task and Calendar tabs:

[image]

If you want to convert your existing classic app to the new lightning one, Salesforce clones the old one for you (with the "Upgrade" button) into a new one, so you cannot really stay with your old app, but this is good enough (for me):

[image]